# Is there a way to pass the request parameter to the /health endpoint in webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am writing a custom REACTIVE Health Indicator (i.e. by implementing ReactiveHealthIndicator) to check the connectivity to another app. However to check this I require some request parameter in the request URL of /health endpoint.(e.g. URL that i want is "/health?countryCode=IN") is there a way to achieve this? Please note that as it is reactive, autowiring HttpServletRequest won't work.

```
@Component

public class CustomServicesHealthIndicator implements ReactiveHealthIndicator {

     @Override
    public Mono<Health> health() {

        //@TODO : This will be called like localhost:8080/acuator/health?param=value.
        // Need to read value of 'param' here and take some actions accordingly
        return doHealthCheck() 
                .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just(new Health.Builder().down(ex).build()));
    }

    private Mono<Health> doHealthCheck(){

        return Mono.just(new Health.Builder().up().build());
    }
}
```

Documentation : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#reactive-health-indicators

Comment: reading the documentation, no, reading the source code, no.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf - added link to documentation as well as code. Also added TODO comment in code to elaborate what I need guidance in.
Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: and as i wrote, it is NOT included in the spring boot documentation, and reading the source code of spring boot there is NO such support, you need to solve your problem in a different way.

Comment: yes...documentation is not helping...neither the code..Thanks @ThomasAndolf.